# jquery get visible html div content loaded by ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How I get the current html content of a div when content is loaded through ajax ?

```
<div class='container'></div>
```

Here `data` is the ajax response.

```
$('.container').html(data);
```

then, user makes some changes to the data.

After that, I need to get the final html.

Comment: What is "the final html"? Provide more context in your question, e.g, post relevant code

Comment: the data returned from ajax is a grid. according to the user actions, some content of this grid will be changed , so I need to get the grid after the changes of the user .

thank you in advance @A. Wolff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at jQuery's AJAX methods. The easiest one for you to use would be `$.get()`:

```
var pageurl="ajax/test.html"
$.get(pageurl, function( data ) {
    $( ".container" ).html( data );
    alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: my point isn't here, it's after load the data > then > actions by user that will modify on data > I would like to get the data after the user's modify

Comment: You need to include more relevant code. It is difficult to understand the concept.

Comment: I think rooxo posted what you need. But this is not what you asked in the question title...very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want element.innerHTML. It returns the content of your element